# "...waking up to each other’s warmth..." Is this phrase grammatical?

Tags: grammar, phrases

> A couple waking up to each other’s warmth in the morning.

I think this sentence is grammatical. However, it only has [1](https://www.google.com.tw/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1ASUT_enTW470TW470&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#sourceid=chrome-psyapi2&ie=UTF-8&q=%22waking%20up%20to%20each%20other%E2%80%99s%20warmth%22) Google result. So, I'm wondering: is it grammatical?

Comment: It's fine (though it's only a sentence fragment). Like a photo caption. A man eating a donut.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing wrong with it at all. What you have to be a little careful of however is that some readers may over-intellectualise and see an unintended hidden meaning.

The phrase is associated with Schopenhauer's Porcupines (sometimes simplified as the hedgehogs' dilemma).

To paraphrase, two porcupines wished to "benefit from each other's warmth" on a cold night but, each time they huddled up, they pricked each other with their quills and had to move apart, eventually settling on a compromise distance that allowed some sharing of warmth without injury.

Reference to Freud's take on it here [Freud: From Individual Psychology to Group Psychology](http://books.google.com.au/books?id=TahwUuLiZc4C&pg=PA168&lpg=PA168&dq=%22each%20other%E2%80%99s%20warmth%22&source=bl&ots=H1XLJ1GWVo&sig=0jWCLKhRZ4QPhhE5caKYu5ypuPo&hl=en&sa=X&ei=8xeFVOXKPM-j8AXN64DgCQ&ved=0CDgQ6AEwBjgK#v=onepage&q=%22each%20other%E2%80%99s%20warmth%22&f=false) with two uses of your phrase.